# Keyboard layout : is there a way to type several chars at once?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to set xkb to type character combinations when I press a single key. I am currently developing my own keyboard layout and I would be glad to be able to configure some keys to insert whole strings instead of chars. I want this because in my language, some char combinations are ways more frequent than some letters of the keyboard.

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you can pick up some ideas from how Chinese and Japanese are written (how to write the characters, that represent words rather than sounds).

Comment: As @sudodus indicated, that would not be done as an XKB keyboard layout, but you'd probably need to create an input method for e.g. IBus and/or Fcitx.